# Is it possible to make an instance of CM applet?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

This is contents of my card :

```
GP: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

GP:
```

As far as I know, the above output means that I have a package on my card (with AID=`A0000001515350`) and in this package there is an applet (with AID=`A000000151535041`). And also there is an applet instance on my card with AID=`A000000151000000`.And this applet instance is **certainly** the instance of the applet of the package (Is all of this conclusions right?)

Now, I want to make another instance of the applet. So I tried the below code :

```
GP: gp -create AABBCCDDEE -package A0000001515350 -applet A000000151535041
openkms.gp.GPException: Install for Install and make selectable failed SW: 6985
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:924)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.installAndMakeSelecatable(GlobalPlatform.ja
va:676)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:353)

GP:
```

Why I receive this error? Is it prevented to create instances of CardManager applet? Why? So how I can have more than one Security Domain? (I mean SSD)

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet figured out sensible user interface for security domains and this is unfinished feature.

You need to be using latest Git version and specify `-sdomain` to `-create`

Comment: Thank you Martin.
Am I right in the first paragraph expressions? 
And also "Theoretically, I can make an instance of CM", right?